# JSP Form and Struts 1

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have made a JSP form. It contains a simple a list of MCQ's that contains radio buttons for each option for every question.

How do I make a struts 1 form that retrieves the users selected answers and compare them to the right answers which are defined in the class.

It should display the users answers and print "correct" if the users option was the correct one.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
<html:form action="/Ans" >
         <h3>What is 2+2</h3>
         1<html:radio name="MCQForm" property="usrAnswers" value="1"  disabled="false"/><br>
         4<html:radio name="MCQForm" property="usrAnswers" value="4"  disabled="false"/><br>
         2<html:radio name="MCQForm" property="usrAnswers" value="2"  disabled="false"/><br>             

    <html:submit value="Submit" />
</html:form>
```

I have managed to create a simple MCQ for one question.

Now how will i Implement an array. How will I map the 2nd radio buttons and compare them with the 2nd index of `Answers[] Array` which contains the right answer for every question.

Comment: You did ask this previously but you deleted the question.

Comment: I thought that it was too broad of a question so I broke it down.

Comment: Are the questions and answers stored in a persistence storage, e.g DB or file system?

Comment: No db or file required...it is just a simple form and requesting using get method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing this:

Either you have an action form that has all specified attributes for your questions e.g.

```
public class MultipleChoiceForm extends ActionForm {

    private String answer1;
    private String answer2;
    private String answer3;

    //continue till end of questions, e.g. this assumes you have 10 questions
    private String answer10;

    //Generate Getters and Setters for your variables;

}
```

OR, have a class that has an array (of String, in this case). This is more tricky as you will have to map your array to a questionId somehow.

Example:

```
public class MultipleChoiceForm extends ActionForm {

    private String[] answers;

    //Getters and Setters here.

}
```

and then your JSP will be something of this sort (repeated many times for all the answer fields you need):

```
<html:text name="multipleChoiceForm" property="answers">
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: why use textfield when we can use radio button?

Comment: It's just an example, you can use radio buttons, etc.

Comment: Where will i define the logic for comparing answers

Comment: and how did you declare `/Ans` in `struts-config.xml`?